# Two Inner Joins MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

How would I preform two inner joins in one query?

Ie: three tables

Invoice
Address
Client

Invoice has a column which references an id in clients. It also has a column which references an address. I need to get both the clients name from the matched table and the address from the matched table. How would I `INNER JOIN` both tables?

I'll add a few details...
invoice has rows address(references address id), client(references client id), id and notes
client has rows first_name, last_name
address has rows street_name and city

I need to pull up

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can have as many JOIN clauses as you need in the query. Each has an ON clause where you specify the related columns between the joined tables.

```
SELECT
  columns
FROM
  invoice
INNER JOIN
  address
ON
  join_condition
INNER JOIN
  client
ON
  join_condition
```

Comment: I was not aware of this. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
  c.*, i.*, a.* 
FROM 
  invoices i 
INNER JOIN 
  client c 
ON 
  i.clientid = c.clientid 
INNER JOIN 
  address a 
ON 
  a.clientid = c.clientid 
WHERE 
  i.id = 21
```

Don't forget you only select the fields you require, not * (all).

Answer (score 0):

A sample e.g. based on learning from [@Dan Grossman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916960) above:

```
SELECT FILM.TITLE, ACTOR.FIRST_NAME, ACTOR.LAST_NAME FROM ACTOR
INNER JOIN FILM_ACTOR
ON ACTOR.ACTOR_ID = FILM_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
INNER JOIN FILM
ON FILM_ACTOR.FILM_ID = FILM.FILM_ID
WHERE ACTOR.FIRST_NAME = 'Nick' AND ACTOR.LAST_NAME = 'Wahlberg'
```